# Get Channel and User ID from Watson Customer Engagement on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-watson

I want to get the Channel and User Id from the registration of  MCE SDK on the Watson platform. I was able to get the information on Android using the following code:

```
RegistrationClient client = MceSdk.getRegistrationClient();
RegistrationDetails details = client.getRegistrationDetails(this);

String channelID = registrationDetails.getChannelId();
String userID = registrationDetails.getUserId();
```

Does anyone knows how to get the same information of the SDK on iOS side? I tried with different ways and the only detail I was able to get is the SDK Version and the App Key with this:

```
let sdkVersion = MCESdk.shared.sdkVersion()
let appKey = MCESdk.shared.config.appKey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I was looking on the wrong object, all the details are on the class MCERegistrationDetails.

```
let appKey = MCERegistrationDetails.shared.appKey
let channelId = MCERegistrationDetails.shared.channelId
let userId = MCERegistrationDetails.shared.userId
```